# Voip push notification crashed on iPhone 7 with iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voip

I'm working on voip notification implementation.
My build is working fine on device iPhone 6 with iOS 11.3.
But it crashed on iPhone 7 with iOS 10.3.3 version with following error:

**pushregistry:didreceiveincomingpushwithpayload:fortype:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Please help me if any body faces such problem.

Comment: Can you please add code for the Function "didreceiveincomingpushwithpayload" and also the payload data you are receiving with notification.
According to this 
https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/issues/124
You are trying to get some key which is not present.

Comment: I think you have to implement 

pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:withCompletionHandler:  as well for below ios 11

Comment: Hi right now I'm using
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {}

Comment: You mean to say I also need to implement following delegate:
    @nonobjc func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {}

Comment: Yes exactly add same delegate without completion handler. like that,
pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType () -> Void) {}

Comment: thanks aBilal ....thanks for your suggestion ...now PKPushPayload working fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

The delegate method is deprecated from iOS11.
So please do the below delegates according to your OS version

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 11.0)
public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
//do the necessary operations
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
//do the necessary operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented delegate method with completion handler like below.

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload 
         forType:(PKPushType)type withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

Please implement same delegate method without completion handler as well like below.

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload 
         forType:(PKPushType)type;
```

Do let me know if you required more help.